# How to use target blank to open urls in different tabs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open some url in new tabs, I want that every time I click on some button it will open up a new tab different tab. I am using window.open for this and this is opening my url in one single new tab..

My code is

window.open("myurl.com", "target=_blank"); "return false;";

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

window.open("myurl.com", "_blank");

Answer (score 0):

Another ugly way using jQuery:

```
$('<a href="myurl.com" target="_blank"></a>')[0].click()
```